# Monitor/audit file delete on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

One of the .beam files of one of my application deps is being deleted and I am not sure by what/how.

Is there a way to monitor or audit a file to see what happens when it is deleted?

I'm using RedHat distro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use the audit daemon. You did't say which Linux distro. Red Hat based systems contain auditd, and you can use auditctl to add rules.

To watch a directory recursively for changes:

```
auditctl -w /usr/local/someapp/ -p wa
```

To watch system calls made by a program with pid of 2021:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -S all -F pid=2021
```

Check the man page for auditctl.

Results will be logged to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

To ensure it's running.

```
/etc/init.d/auditd status
```

For a more thorough approach, you could use tripwire or OSSEC, but they're geared more toward intrusion detection.

Comment: I am using RedHat and that sounds ideal, I'll try it out tomorrow before accepting this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a desription about how to search for the file deletions in the log: https://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-list/2011-April/msg00001.html

`auditctl -w /home/user/folder -k whodeletedit -p wa`

`ausearch -i -k whodeletedit | grep "DELETE"`

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor your Linux file system using aide. AIDE means Intrusion Detection Software to Monitor Changes. 
Steps:

1. Install AIDE  #yum install aide -y
2. Configuration AIDE // PERMS=p+i+u+g+acl+selinux
3. Initialize the AIDE database #aide –-init
4. Check the file system changes #aide –-check

To get more details you can visit below link
http://topicsfeedback.com/linux-system-monitoring-tools/
or you may download best android apps about advance Linux in your phone to get instant access 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.topicsfeedback.advancelinux