# Is there a way of finding out what program is deleting my files, in linux?

Tags: linux

I am having an issue where files are being deleted by some program, in a system that is fully automated, any way of finding what is the culprit, or setting something up to find the culprit.

Thanks, for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Monitor/audit file delete on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519590/monitor-audit-file-delete-on-linux)

Comment: ...also, off-topic as it is unrelated to programming.